# Add generated Python file as part of build

Tags: python, code-generation, distutils

I am generating some Python files in my `setup.py` as part of the build process. These files should be part of the installation. I have successfully added my code generator as a pre-build step (by implementing my own `Command` and overriding the default `build` to include this).

How do I copy my generated files from the temporary directory into the build output? Should I copy it myself using e.g. `copy_file`? If so, how do I get the path to the build output? Or should I declare it as part of the build somehow?

I'd rather not clutter the source directory tree with my generated files, hence I prefer to avoid copying the files there and then declaring them as part of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by subclassing `build_py` instead of `build`. It turns out `build_py` has a `build_lib` attribute that will be the path to the "build" directory.

By looking at the source code I think there is no better way.